# Ros map exploration (searching for some objects)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to explore map (room) with turtlebot + kinect and search for some objects in it. So far I've done object detector and it works ok.

The problem now is how to explore map in some intelligent way (not just random movement). I've been searching for something that already exists in this way but the best I could find was exploration pack.
If there is no such package how would be the easiest way for me to star build my own? I've used move_base goal in previous experiment to move turtlebot slalom between some comes, I suppose I could do something similar now but with whole room, but I don't think this is the best way. I've been thinking that if I have to use my own goals etc. the best thing would be to create whole global planner, but I don't have any idea on how to even start building it.

Can you please help me with some suggestions.

EDIT:

As I said I already have build working code for object recognition. I only need for robot to move through whole room, for it to see objects.

How would I make [explore](http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore) work with turtlebot? If I start turtlebot (bringup etc.) and load map using

> roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml

it just says

> Done exploring with 0 goals left that could not be reached. There are 0 goals on our blacklist, and 0 of the frontier goals are too close to them to pursue. The rest had global planning fail to them.
> Exploration finished. Hooray.

But does [explore](http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore) work with built map? As far as I understand [explore](http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore) pack is used to autonomously create map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38861/ros-map-exploration-(searching-for-some-objects)/) by [Darkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2850/darkmaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-02**:
Hi, I want a clear answer, If I give the robot a map and can navigate on the environment then I want it to search for a object and when fine it, robot stop and do music
so can explore be used for this purpose >>> thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A frontier based exploration stack already exists. Please refer link for package [explore](http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore) in exploration stack. I believe searching for some object functionality is not part of exploration stack.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-26**:
@prince  Done exploring with 0 goals left that could not be reached. There are 0 goals on our blacklist, and 0 of the frontier goals are too close to them to pursue. The rest had global planning fail to them.
Exploration finished. Hooray.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-26**:
I start turtlebot (bringup etc.) and load map using

```
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml
```

it just says the up comment

??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could imagine the problem with the explore package is that it considers everything covered by LIDAR data as explored. If you're interested in getting a floor plan that's fine. OTOH, if you are interested in coverage of the environment by a sensor with much shorter range (and different FOV) than your LIDAR, this approach of course won't work well. In that case, you'd have to generate a separate appropriate map and feed that to the exploration approach you're using.

On a related note, we plan on publishing our [exploration transform](https://www.uni-koblenz.de/%7Eagas/Documents/Wirth2007ETA1.pdf) implementation [successfully used in the RoboCup Rescue competition](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=486860097994941&set=a.477301558950795.127503.415076305173321&type=1&theater) in the coming weeks, so later you could also try that.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1